# Compiling MikeOS on a 64x computer

Tags: assembly, 32bit-64bit, windows-10-desktop

I have recently decided that it would be fun to try playing around with MikeOS. It started off good but then things took a turn for the worst. During compiling I found that I needed a piece of software called partcopy. I looked around and you apparently need a 32x computer to use it. I only have a 64x computer and I can't figure out how to install and run this one piece of software. I am using the unmodified MikeOs code. I don't know what else to do! Plese help!!

Comment: 32-bit Windows application run under 64-bit versions of Windows. If it doesn't install or run correctly then there's some other problem.

Comment: You'll probably have to use [DD](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) ro create disk images (and place your bootloader on it etc). If need be [Virtual Floppy Drive](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/simplified_x86x64_virtual_floppy_drive_(vfd).html) can be used to mount disk images you make so that they can be formatted or files can be copied onto a file system present on the dik image.